# DAX Count Down Over (remaining)

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, dax, ssas-tabular

I wanted to calculate the column `RestOrder` in DAX. Can you guys please help? The `TotalOrderDay` column was calculated with the `Allexcept()` formula. I need something like calculate the orders for `Statedate` remaining or so...or a SQL "rownumber over partition by kinda thing".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRbhB.jpg]

Thanks for help!

Comment: thanks @Thielicious

Answer (score 1):

The following DAX can do:

```
RestOrder = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        'Order',
        'Order'[StateDate].[Date] = EARLIER('Order'[StateDate].[Date]) &&
        'Order'[StateDate] >= EARLIER('Order'[StateDate])
    )
)
```

Results:

[image: results]

So what you're trying to achieve is to count the number of orders, which are of the same date but is earlier than others.

In order to achieve so, your `Statedate` has to be in `Datetime` type.

Comment: Hi @andy does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.